# Adding a fixed table to layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I wonder how to add a fixed table into QGIS layout.

I've tried this solution but it doesn't work :

```
model = MyOwnQgsFeatureFilterModel(layout)
tableEnsemble = QgsLayoutFrame(layout, model)
tableEnsemble.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(float(tblEnsbl.minX), float(tblEnsbl.minY), QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
tableEnsemble.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(float(tblEnsbl.maxX), float(tblEnsbl.maxY), QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
layout.addLayoutItem(tableEnsemble)
```

I get an empty table like this "multiframe":

[image]

Instead, I want the table frame I created myself in the layout, not by code.

Comment: What is `tblEnsbl`?

Comment: it's an object that i have it contains many numbers as string that i convert to float

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but an answer

```py
composerTitle = 'Layout 1'
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
# Access to the layout by name
layout = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName(composerTitle)

# Option 1: considering you selected the created table frame item in the GUI
tableEnsemble = layout.selectedLayoutItems()[0]

# Option 2: if you put an id to your manually created table frame item
tableEnsemble = layout.itemById('own_item')

# Then, change position of your manually created table now you got the reference
tableEnsemble.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(float(tblEnsbl.minX), float(tblEnsbl.minY), QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
tableEnsemble.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(float(tblEnsbl.maxX), float(tblEnsbl.maxY), QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```